# It is possible to prove that there are infinitely many points in space in Hilber'ts axiomatization of geometry?

Tags: geometry, proof-theory, axiomatic-geometry

Dumb question, i know, there's no explicit axiom about it, but it's somehow possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the axioms as usually written is something like, given two points on a line, there exists a point between them on the line.  With this axiom you can construct an infinite sequence of points starting with any $p_0$ and $p_1$, such that $p_i$ is between $p_0$ and $p_{i-1}$ for every $i$, and hence it's between $p_0$ and $p_j$ for every $0<j<i$, and hence it's distinct from all the earlier points.

Comment: @mjqxxxx You have to be really careful here. An affine plane in which every line has $5$ points numbered $0,1,2,3,4$ modulo $5$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is between $a$ and $b$ satisfies that axiom, but is obviously finite. In general, [Pasch's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom) or one of its variants is necessary to get infinitely many points on a line just from betweenness... otherwise the "hence it's between $p_0$ and $p_j$ for every $0<j<i$" doesn't follow.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: ...where $(a+b)/2$ is the number $c$ such that $2c=a+b\pmod 5$, e.g. $(0+1)/2=4$, right? It took me a second to understand your comment.

Comment: @Rahul Right. Writing it $\frac{a+b}{2}$ looks prettier, but something like $2^{-1}(a+b) \bmod 5$ is probably better, and of course we need to check that for three distinct $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ exactly one is between the other two by this definition.

Comment: Whoops, that should have been $(0+1)/2=3$ in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we work with the formulation of Hilbert's axioms [as seen on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms), then the Incidence and Order axioms together (for a plane, so ignore I.4 through I.8 and assume for II.4 that all points are coplanar) are enough to show the existence of infinitely many points.

A rough sketch of the proof is this:

1. Given a line $\ell$, define the "on the same side of $\ell$" relation between points not on $\ell$ as follows: $A$ is on the same side of $\ell$ as $B$ if there is no point of $\ell$ between $A$ and $B$.
2. Using axiom II.2, we can find two points $A$, $B$ not on the same side of $\ell$. Using axiom II.4 (Pasch's axiom), we can show that the "on the same side" relation is an equivalence relation, and that all points are either on the same side of $\ell$ as $A$ or as $B$. We conclude the **Plane separation theorem**: a line separates the plane into two sides.
3. From here, the **Line separation theorem** follows: a point $X$ on a line $\ell$ separates the line into two rays. (Two points $A,B$ are in the same ray relative to $X$ if $A * B * X$ or $B * A * X$.)
4. Finally, we can use induction to find arbitrarily many points on a given line $\ell$. Start with two points $X_1, X_2$ (by axiom I.3) and repeatedly use axiom II.2 to find a point $X_i$ on $\ell$ such that $X_{i-2} * X_{i-1} * X_i$. By the line separation theorem relative to $X_{i-1}$, $X_i$ is a point distinct from $X_1, \dots, X_{i-2}$, because $X_i$ lies in a different ray from all of them.

Comment: Which axioms are giving you **induction**? If none, then you cannot say that Hilbert's axioms "are enough to show the existence of infinitely many points". All you can say is that given any specific **finite** natural number $k$, using Hilbert's axioms you can prove the existence of $k$ distinct points.

Comment: @user21820 Hilbert's axioms and the axiom of induction are different kinds of things. The axiom of induction is part of the formal system we're working in. Hilbert's incidence and order axioms are just properties an ordered geometry has to satisfy. We are proving, within let's say for concreteness ZFC, that any geometry satisfying the subset of Hilbert's axioms mentioned in my answer, there must be infinitely many points.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. It is not stated clearly in your answer, and very misleading to people who do not grasp the distinction between a meta-logical fact (which we have both stated in the comments) and an 'internal' statement within the system itself. Why don't you edit your answer to make that clear?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be clarified since nobody working with Hilbert's axioms or any subset of them **ever** does anything else.

Comment: You are only talking about professionals. No disagreement there. But the asker clearly does not know about it, and similarly many lay readers of your answer will be misled.